# Java Error: Constructor RandomColorListener in class RectanglesGUI.RandomColorListener cannot be applied to given type

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am having a problem on relating a listener to the southButton to handle events.

```
 (southButton.addActionListener(new RandomColorListener(drawPanel));)
```

When the user clicks on the JButton in the SOUTH region, the
rectangles filled with color1 should all change to a random Color,
while the rectangles filled with color2 should not change. A second
click on the JButton should make the rectangles filled with color2 all
change to a random Color, while the rectangles filled with a random
Color by the first click should stay the same Color.

The user should be able to continue clicking on the button indefinitely, and with each click one set of rectangles will be filled with a random Color. In each case, the rectangles to change should be the ones that stayed the same on
the last click (in other words, the Color change should alternate between the two sets of rectangles). This means that with each click only one set of rectangles should change colour.

I tried to pass drawPanel into randomListener but there is this Java error comes out.

> Java Error: Constructor RandomColorListener in class
>   RectanglesGUI.RandomColorListener cannot be applied to given type.

Can somebody tell me what should I do in order to use drawPanel inside class randomListener

```
        import javax.swing.*;
        import java.awt.*;
        import java.awt.event.*;
        import java.util.ArrayList;
        import java.util.List;

        public class RectanglesGUI
        {
            JFrame frame;
            RectangleDrawPanel drawPanel;
            Color color1 = Color.orange;
            Color color2 = Color.blue;
            //Set fixed number of rows and columns
            protected static final int ROWS = 5;
            protected static final int COLS = 5;
            private List<Color>colors;


            public static void main (String[] args)
            {
                RectanglesGUI gui = new RectanglesGUI();
                gui.go();
            }

    //this method sets up the JFrame, adds the button and drawpanel to the frame and adds the ActionListener to the button
        public void go()
        {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        drawPanel = new RectangleDrawPanel();
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, drawPanel);

                //Add a JButton to the SOUTH region of the JFrame using BorderLayout. Set the text on the button.
                JButton southButton = new JButton("Click to CHANGE color on alternate set of Rectangles");
                frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, southButton);


                frame.setSize(600,600);
                frame.setVisible(true);

                //Relate a listener to the southButton to handle events.
                southButton.addActionListener(new RandomColorListener(drawPanel));
                //Relate another listener to northButton.
                northButton.addActionListener(new ResetListener() {});
    }

        //Inner class to implement actionListener and listen to the JButton in the SOUTH region
        class RandomColorListener implements ActionListener
        {
                private RectangleDrawPanel myPanel;
                public RectangleDrawPanel (RectangleDrawPanel aPanel)
                {
                    this.myPanel = aPanel;
                }
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
                {
                    int r = (int)(Math.random()*256);
                    int g = (int)(Math.random()*256);
                    int b = (int)(Math.random()*256);
                    color1 = new Color(r,g,b);

                    RectangleDrawPanel();
                }
        }


    class RectangleDrawPanel extends JPanel{
                @Override
        public void paintComponent (Graphics g)
                {
                    //Store 2 colors Alternatively in the Arraylist using for loop
                    int length = ROWS * COLS;
                    colors = new ArrayList<>(length);
                    for(int i=1;i<=length;i++)
                    {
                        double count;
                        count = i;
                        if(count%2 == 0)
                            {colors.add(color2);}
                        else
                            {colors.add(color1);}
                    }


                    super.paintComponent(g);
                    Graphics2D g2=(Graphics2D)g;

                    //Distribute the rectangles Evenly using for loop and Fill them with colors (from ArrayList) 
                    int rectWidth = getWidth()/5; 
                    int rectHeight = getHeight()/5; 

                    for (int y = 0; y < ROWS; y++) 
                    {
                        for (int x = 0; x < COLS; x++) 
                        {
                            int index=(y * COLS) + x;
                            g2.setColor(colors.get(index));
                            g2.fillRect(x * rectWidth, y * rectHeight, rectWidth, rectHeight);
                        }
                    }


        }
    }
}
```